# Use Arduino to control a stepping motor and receive the feedback

Tags: c++, arduino

I want to use Arduino to control a stepper motor and catch the feedback. After my upper computer catch the feedback there is other work to do after the stepper motor has rotated. The code is as below:

```
int x;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT); // Step  
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT); // Dir
}

void loop() { 
  digitalWrite(4,LOW);

  for(x = 0; x < 3200; x++) // Loop 3200 times  
  {  
    digitalWrite(5,HIGH); // Output high  
    delayMicroseconds(400);   
    digitalWrite(5,LOW); // Output low  
    delayMicroseconds(400);  

  }

  Serial.println("ok");
  delay(1000);
}
```

But before the stepper motor rotate, the upper computer has already received the feedback of "ok". How can I improve my code.

Comment: You loop should be a little over 2.5 seconds. Are you telling us that it's actually quicker than that? Or that the motor can't react in the 0.0004 seconds of time you give it? Maybe you're supposed to sleep 400 *milliseconds* (0.4 seconds)?

Comment: Could you move the motor with this code? I mean, did you receive 'ok' and then the motor rotates?

Comment: the motor works correctly but before the motor rotate , i can receive the "ok".  My goal is get the "ok" after that, so i can do other works which must wait the motor has rotated.

Comment: the function `loop` is called repeatedly, so maybe you received the "ok" from the previous call? The delay between two calls seems to be just one second.

Comment: Wait for the motor to move then send OK, clearly the motor has a delay which you have to wait, which you do not wait now. Measure it and add a delay after to for loop. Get an rotary encoder on that motor if you want actual feedback, all you can do now is guessing.

Comment: It seems like my upper computer receive the "ok" as soon as the motor begins to rotate

Comment: i would try  thinks a lot

Comment: @JunshengShen - You might get higher quality answers on the [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) site. If you search the Q&A there, you might already find what you're looking for. Good luck.